# Authenticating with JWT in Laravel 11

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-11

I have a bearer token that is generated upon successful login. However, when I use this token in the 'auth:api' middleware to recognize the user via `$request->user`, it nullifies my image description. How can I configure my project to apply JWT, without losing anything in the `config/app.php` file?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgKnM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUnEN.png)

I want to fix the problem to run my project.

Comment: You have the `JWT Bearer` type, andyou are using the `Bearer` type, on the postman.